# how to run an application using oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an application which is running on server. Every second my application checks inserted rows in a table. After a row was inserted application sends some necessary info via email. So, connection to DB (means a session) effects to the system performance. It takes a lot of memory.

Is it possible to implement this in a way that Oracle executes a batch file (batch file will execute an application) after a row was inserted? If yes, how to do that?

P.S.: the batch file has already been prepared and it is working fine for me.

Comment: A single connection and session should not take up a significant amount of memory.  I'd look into that before re-engineering the process.

Comment: I agree with you. But this is not only one session in my DB. That is why I want reorganize some applications.

Comment: I'm not sure why the other answers got downvoted, but this does sound like a good time to use triggers.  Or you could create a job through DBMS_SCHEDULER that runs very minute or so and looks for some sort of "not processed" flag.  Another possibility is [continuous query notification](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815).

Comment: Thnx, Jon. I have visited lots of web-resources and come to conclusion that I have to use jobs. So, on my mind your last comment should be an answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods for making the process sort-of asynchronous are:

1. **Triggers** - perhaps an AFTER STATEMENT trigger that kicks off a job.
2. **DBMS_SCHEDULER** - Create a job that runs every X minutes and processes any rows where a flag is not set.  The flag should probably be indexed.
3. **[Continuous query notification‌​](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815)** - To notify the application when a relevant row has changed.